# how to prove that a set A is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A=\{(-1)^n + \frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb N^* \} $. Show that A is bounded

I have tried to use the boundaries of $(-1)^n$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ separately and then combine them by adding both numbers but such method doesn't seem to work actually

Comment: "Such a method doesn't seem to work actually". Why not?

Comment: since after checking the solution the upper bound wasn't as it should for when it should have been 3/2 I found it to be 2 don't know if something wrong from my part but I tried my best in checking it

Comment: If the single credited response is 3/2 than the question is written poorly. For 3/2 is *an* upper bound, as is 2 or any number larger. 3/2 is the *maximum* element in the sequence, but that's not what the question asked for.

Comment: well actually the question asked later for infA and supA but these were proved after proving that the set A is bounded

Comment: (+1) @AliHaroon: People may have misunderstood your question and assumed you were asking for a homework solution, rather than asking about the difference between _an_ upper bound ($2$) and the _least upper bound_ ($3/2$).

Answer (score 1):

For all $x\in A$,
$$-\pi^\frac{\sqrt[4]{973}}{5}\leq x\leq \frac{7\arctan\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)e^{\sqrt 2}}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{8})}.$$

Comment: Naughty boy... The canonical answer in such cases should be 42.

Answer (score 0):

Bounds coming from the triangle inequality are not generally optimal, even if "the individual bounds are optimal".

For example, if $|a_{n}| \leq 1$ with equality for some $n$, and if $|b_{n}| \leq 1$ with equality for some $n$, then $|a_{n} + b_{n}| \leq 2$, but it need not happen that $|a_{n} + b_{n}| = 2$ for some $n$.